# How use BoxLayout from KivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Why can I move the button only horizontally using the vertical orientation of BoxLayout, and only vertically using the horizontal orientation? For example:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
    KV = '''
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            MDRaisedButton:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .3,'center_y': .5}
    '''
    class Test(MDApp):
        def build(self):
            return Builder.load_string(KV)
    Test().run()
```

**Horizontal orientation, also the default orientation:**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
KV = '''
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        MDRaisedButton:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .3,'center_y': .5}
'''
class FindWord(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
FindWord().run()
```

How to move widgets freely on both axes? Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.app import MDApp

KV = '''
MDScreen:

    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_size: True
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .3, 'center_y': .5}

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "MDRaisedButton"
'''


class FindWord(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


FindWord().run()
```

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html